# python variable value after assignment

Tags: python

I'm new to python and in the process of rewriting an old python script and I came across the following line:

```
some_list = #some list with data
some_variable = [x[0] for x in some_list]
```

what's `x[0]`? I don't see `x` declared previously, is it being created on this line?

what would the value or some_variable be? a list?

***update***

by 'x' i'm referring to `x[0]`, not the x in the for loop

Comment: Yes, `x` comes from this line. `for x in some_list`. This is a list comprehension.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case  `some_list` is a list of sequences, e.g. Lists, tuples, dicts or strings. In your brackets, called a list comprehension, you iterate through `some_list`. x is the current element of some_list, from which you take the first element `x[0]` and put it in the new list.

Comment: cool stuff, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

x is the iterating element in your for-loop